# Google Cloud BigQuery Admin service account gets "does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission"

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I'm new to Google Cloud & BigQuery. I reviewed the dozen other questions that seem to be related and have not seen what I'm missing from those answers. I'm trying to query a public dataset.

The error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access Denied: Project airy-advantage-235802: The user kafka-learning@airy-advantage-235802.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project airy-advantage-235802.",
    "reason" : "accessDenied"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Denied: Project airy-advantage-235802: The user kafka-learning@airy-advantage-235802.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project airy-advantage-235802."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:401)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1132)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:499)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:183)
```

What I've done:

1. Created new Google Cloud account
2. Created new project, which Google assigned the project ID airy-advantage-235802, project name is Kafka Learning.
3. Created a service account kafka-learning@airy-advantage-235802.iam.gserviceaccount.com
4. Granted that user the BigQuery Admin role within the project (I originally tried BigQuery User and BigQuery Data Viewer)
5. I saved the JSON credentials file to a local folder
6. I set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path to the JSON file
7. I have a [tiny Java project to query a public dataset](https://github.com/samuelneff/kafka-learning/blob/75d436cf0590401a7b3f8f10e4422448100da33c/bigquery-producer/src/main/java/com/serndesign/kafka/learning/bigqueryProducer/App.java)
8. Received above error
9. Verified billing is enabled (as far as I can tell, see below)

Is there a step I missed?

[image: Google Cloud Project setup]

[image: Service Account Setup]

[image]

```
var bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
var query = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160801` LIMIT 10";
var queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();
var table = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
```

I've also tried explicitly setting the project id (which is also in the json file) by changing the builder to this:

```
var bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("airy-advantage-235802").build().getService();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when you delete and create a service account with the same name as the "new" service account may have old roles binding to it. Thus, you could:

- Use a new service account
- Explicitly removing any bindings granting that role to the service account
- Re-granting those roles to the "new" service account.

For more information, you could check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be exactly the issue. I created a new service account with a new name and the same permissions and it worked fine this time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem too. Reading the docs you will solve it.

It is possible to delete a service account and then create a new service account with the same name. If you reuse the name of a deleted service account, it may result in unexpected behavior.

When you delete a service account, its role bindings are not immediately deleted. If you create a new service account with the same name as a recently deleted service account, the old bindings may still exist; however, they will not apply to the new service account even though both accounts have the same email address. This behavior occurs because service accounts are given a unique ID within Cloud IAM at creation. Internally, all role bindings are granted using these IDs, not the service account's email address. Therefore, any role bindings that existed for a deleted service account do not apply to a new service account that uses the same email address.

To avoid confusion, we suggest using unique service account names. If this is not possible, you can grant a role to the new service account by:

Explicitly removing all bindings granting that role to the old service account.
Re-granting those roles to the new service account.
You must remove the role bindings first before re-adding them. Simply granting the role again will silently fail by granting the role to the old, deleted service account.  [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)